# Modifying PageRoute Controller using ModalRoute 'can only be used within instance members..'

Tags: flutter, protected, inherited, animationcontroller

I have a Widget that based on certain user interactions modifies the AnimationController of the PageRoute.

It does this via `ModalRoute.of(context)?.controller` and whilst it works as expected it is flagged as an invalid use of a protected member.

```
static void animateController(BuildContext context, double value){
  route?.controller  // flag
        ?.animateTo(
          value.clamp(0, 1),
          curve: Curves.easeOutCubic,
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 360),
        )
}

// flag :: The member 'controller' can only be used within instance members of subclasses of 'package:flutter/src/widgets/routes.dart'.dart(invalid_use_of_protected_member)
```

Whilst this still works, clearly it is not the correct approach. I could build a custom `PageRoute<T>`, a separate `InheritedWidget` that contains the controller and then create a static function but that seems quite unnecessary when it works with `ModalRoute`.

I presume I'm getting this flag because the controller is annotated as protected. What is the best way to access and adjust this controller in child widgets.